# Cannot UnitTest my repository with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, unit-testing, android-testing

I'm trying to run my unit test that contains Firebase code, I have mocked everything that I need and also initialized FirebaseApp.initialize(context) before running my test.

This is my test code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class HelpRepositoryImplTest {

    private lateinit var helpRepository: HelpRepository

    @Mock
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    @Mock
    private lateinit var firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore

    @Mock
    private lateinit var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser

    @Mock
    private lateinit var collectionReference: CollectionReference

    private val testDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext)
        helpRepository = HelpRepositoryImpl(dispatcher = testDispatcher)
    }

    @Test
    fun send_message_test() = runBlocking {
        val message = "Test message"
        val userMail = "test9@firebase.com"
        val documentReference = mock<DocumentReference>()
        val task: Task<DocumentReference> = Tasks.forResult(documentReference)

        whenever(firebaseAuth.currentUser).thenReturn(firebaseUser)
        whenever(firebaseUser.email).thenReturn(userMail)
        whenever(firebaseFirestore.collection(any())).thenReturn(collectionReference)
        whenever(collectionReference.add(SuggestionMessage(message, userMail))).thenReturn(task)

        val messageResult = helpRepository.sendSuggestionMessage(message)
        assertTrue(task.isSuccessful)
        assertTrue(messageResult.isSuccess)
        assertEquals(Unit, messageResult.getOrNull())
    }
}
```

The test is under `test` package , not `androidTest` (because I need to use mockito)

This is my repository

```
class HelpRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(@IoDispatcher private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) :
    HelpRepository {

    override suspend fun sendSuggestionMessage(message: String): Result<Unit> {
        return withContext(dispatcher) {
            try {
                val userMail = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.email ?: "no-email"
                Firebase.firestore.collection("messages").add(SuggestionMessage(message, userMail))
                    .await()
                Result.success(Unit)
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                Result.failure(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a very simple example, but it crash with the following message

> No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering
> instrumentation. java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation
> registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.

At line

```
  FirebaseApp.initializeApp(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext)
```

Comment: There are a lot of questions on Stack Overflow about the error message "No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation." You might want to say more about what you tried that you learned from those questions in order to avoid this question being marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I have tried moving to a different package (androidTest), I also tried with ApplicationProvider to get the context, also tried without initializing Firebase and tried to mock the context, could not do it also, I have tried those ways but still facing the same issue, I have updated the dependencies and still the same.